# Difficulty Training and Evaluating Neural Network Using DL4J, ND4J and Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to create, train and evaluate a neural network by using deeplearning4j, nd4j and spark.  I am able to feed the neural network data in the form of an RDD, however, when I try to evaluate how well the neural network was trained with this line of code:

```
lazy val evaluation_Regression_RMSE = 
trainLayer.evaluateRegression(testingDfConverted).rootMeanSquaredError(0)
println(evaluation_Regression_RMSE)
```

I receive this error:

org.nd4j.linalg.exception.ND4JIllegalStateException: op.X length should be 
equal to op.Y length: [[2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 99]] != [[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 99]] at 
org.nd4j.linalg.cpu.nativecpu.ops.NativeOpExecutioner.exec(NativeOpExecutioner.java:475)

Does anyone know what is happening here and how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your labels and output array sizes don't match up. It's showing there that you have a 1 x 2 vs a 1 x 1.